# 関数を引数とする関数について

Tags: c

c言語では関数を引数にとる関数を定義できて、

```
double calc1(double a);
double calc2(double func(double),double a){
    return func(a);
}
```

のようにすれば、

```
calc2(calc1,a);
```

という計算ができますが、calc1が2変数関数だったときに、

```
double calc1(double a,double b);
```

「calc1のaにある変数を代入した関数」をcalc2に渡すことはできますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ご質問のように多引数の関数の一部の引数に値を与えて、より引数の少ない関数を得ることを「部分適用」と言ったりしますが、C言語そのものには部分適用を簡単に表現する機構はありません。(特殊なABIを採用するコンパイラで、比較的簡単にそんなことができるものもあるようですが。)

別に1引数の中間関数を定義する必要があるでしょう。

```
double calc1(double a, couble b);

double calc1partial5(double b) {
    return calc1(5.0, b);
}

calc2(calc1partial5, a);
```

「calc1のaにある変数を代入」の「ある変数」がローカル変数だったりすると、通常のC言語の関数として構成するのは無理だろうと思います。

Answer (score 3):

GCC の [Nested Function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) を使う方法もあるのかなと思ったのですが、

```
#include <stdio.h>

double calc1(double a, double b) {
  return a + b;
}

double (*calc2(double func(double, double), double a))(double){
  double calc3(double b) {
    return func(a, b);
  }
  return calc3;
}

int main () {
  double x = 1;
  double y = 2;
  double (*f)(double) = calc2(calc1, x);
  printf("%f\n", f(y));
}
```

[Nested Function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html)

> If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function exits, **all hell breaks loose**.

まぁ、当然そうなりますよね。。。

参考にはなりませんけど、なんだかもったいない様な気がするのでので回答？として上げておきます。